# Why doesn't phone android chrome emulation work properly?

Tags: android, google-chrome, responsive-design

So i have my website and on all emulation stuff i tried so far it looks good, but on phone it becomes messed up. I am testing in chrome vs nexus 5 chrome. The problem i'm encountering is some of my product elements which display 2 on a row when on phone sometimes get an unequal height and that causes a white space in one of the slots close to it.

Comment: Did you use the mobile device emulation in Google dev tools, or just resized the screen?

Comment: i used the emulation, of course. even fiddled around with user agents around a bit

Comment: Good. I think it only emulates the screen size, the user agent, the network speed and touch interfaces. It will not emulate different chrome versions and hardware other limitations. You should try some service like BrowserStack - the next best thing after the actual hardware.

Comment: well, it should. at least at a basic level, like android and whatnot